# Can't log in to Oracle EM Fusion Middleware Control 12c even after starting nodemanager, weblogic and forms server. Host:7001, error page

Tags: oracle, localhost, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

[login page reloading unevenly (host:7001/em)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMFwf.png)

[weblogic command not responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuAjW.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the future, it would be helpful if you include details.  In other words for example you said there is an error, but you did not provide any details about the error.  Is there an error number? What about the error text?

You also did not mention exactly which software versions you are using or the platform on which it is installed.  This is all important information needed to help get you accurate and helpful information.

Given the lack of information, all I can do is assume you are using 12.2.1.4.  If so, install Oracle Patch 30613424

Also, a quick glance at your images, it is possible that your failure is related to having not started in an elevated DOS shell.  You must start the servers in an elevated shell ("Run as administrator").  This is not the same as being a member of the Administrator group.

Also, are you familiar with the Oracle Forms Forum? It is a good source of information and help when needed.

https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/categories/forms